# Выпадающий список не реализуется при :hover

Tags: html, css

При наведении здесь - *h3:hover .dropdown_content* - почему-то не срабатывает выпадающий список.

```css
h3 {
  line-height: 2;
  margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #a87f5c;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
h3:hover .dropdown_content {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 5px 0 #a87f5c;
}

.dropdown_content {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
.dropdown_content a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a87f5c;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  transition: .6s all ease;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dropdown_content a:hover {
  color: #0e1d26;
  margin-left: 15px;
  transition: .6s all ease;
}
```

```html
                    <h3 href="pages/production.html">Продукция/портфолио</h3>
                    <div class="dropdown_content">
                        <a href="pages/tables.html">Столы</a>
                        <a href="pages/storage.html">Мебель <br>для хранения</a>
                        <a href="pages/interior.html">Интерьер</a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что данный вариант правил работает только со вложенными элементами.

```css
    h3 {
      line-height: 2;
      margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #a87f5c;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      border: 1px dotted black;
    }
    .dropdown_content {
      display: none;
      padding: 10px 25px;
    }
    .wrap:hover .dropdown_content {
      display: block;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: white;
      box-shadow: -1px -1px 5px 0 #a87f5c;
    }

    
    .dropdown_content a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #a87f5c;
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: left;
      display: block;
      transition: .6s all ease;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      width: 250px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .dropdown_content a:hover {
      color: #0e1d26;
      margin-left: 15px;
      transition: .6s all ease;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <h3 href="pages/production.html">Продукция/портфолио</h3>
    <div class="dropdown_content">
    <a href="pages/tables.html">Столы</a>
    <a href="pages/storage.html">Мебель <br>для хранения</a>
    <a href="pages/interior.html">Интерьер</a>
  </div>
</div>
```